# Including CPPUnit test in visualcode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cppunit

I'm working on this tutorial from:
http://www.evocomp.de/tutorials/tutorium_cppunit/howto_tutorial_cppunit.html
and I am not able to include headers from the CPPUnit directory in Visual Code on mac. The CPPUnit is installed on my ~ folder such as for an example header file like HelperMacos.h,v the path is:

```
~/cppunit-cvs-repo-archive/cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h,v
```

I have tried to include the path under `includePath` section in `c_cpp_properties.json` by adding this line:

```
 "~/cppunit-cvs-repo-archive/cppunit/",
"~/cppunit-cvs-repo-archive/cppunit/include/",
"~/cppunit-cvs-repo-archive/cppunit/extensions/"
```

for including the header files in my visual studio code but the program is giving me an error. For example it says:
`cannot open source file "cppunit/TestCaller.h" (dependency of "cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h,v")` when I try to include:

```
#include <cppunit/exetnsions/HelperMacros.h,v>
```

Comment: `HelperMacros.h,v` ?? shouldn't it be `HelperMacros.h`?

Comment: ***cannot open source file "cppunit/TestCaller.h"*** Seems like you should check if that file exists. We have no idea of what files you have on your system.

Comment: That is the header file name in the installed CPPUnit directory. I still dont understand what the h,v means.

Comment: @drescherjm the file does exist.

Comment: Then your problem is you have to add the folder containing `cppunit` to your include paths. I believe that is `"~/cppunit-cvs-repo-archive/"`

Comment: Seems like something has gone wrong with your installation. The file should be called `HelperMacros.h`, see here for example, http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/cppunit_cookbook.html

Comment: Also called `HelperMacros.h` in the tutorial you are following.

Comment: I installed it correctly, i reinstalled it as well it gives me the header file. It is still giving me error saying the included file wasn't found. I have uploaded the files on my github : <https://github.com/vipulroxx/learn-c-> in the directory ```cppunittuts ```. All the header files for the CPPUnit framework is in the directory ``` cppunit-cvs-repo-archive ```

Answer (score 0):

The correct setting for `includePath` in `c_cpp_properties.json` in case of the original question should be something like the following

```
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "~/cppunit-cvs-repo-archive/"
],
"macFrameworkPath": [
    "/System/Library/Frameworks", 
    "/Library/Frameworks"
],
```

The cppunit installation location has to be specified only up to the root directory that contains the cppunit directory.

The system library include paths are specified on Mac via the `macFrameworkPath` property as mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference).